# take a screenshot with code in objective-c and send to text

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a button in my iOS game app (written in objective-c and cocos2d) that lets users open a text message with their score and a message, for sharing with friends.

I have just seen on another different app a similar button, but this app takes a screenshot of your score and attaches it to the text message as well.

That is a very cool feature, but I have no idea how they do that.

Any clues??

It is just a simple button in the app, and tapping on it opens up the iPhone message app with a screenshot of their game and a prefilled text message.

No screenshot is saved to the photo album. The screenshot is taken automatically and only added to the text message.

I would love to know how they did that!

Comment: try to use MFMessageComposeViewController!

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code snippet.

```
-(UIImage*) drawText:(NSString*) text
         inImage:(UIImage*)  image
         atPoint:(CGPoint)   point {

UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height)];
CGRect rect = CGRectMake((image.size.width - 205), (image.size.height - 18), image.size.width, image.size.height);
[[UIColor redColor] set];
[text drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(rect) withFont:font];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage;
```

}

Also you can arrange the text position on image. Simply implemantation is added below.

```
UIImage *resultImage = [self drawText:@"ehliyetCepte is a best app in the AppStore" inImage:sharedImageView.image atPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
```